# Oracle SQL Server with JDBC to use with PHP

Tags: php, jdbc, apache2, php-7

I have access/ credentials to an Oracle SQL Server (not installed on my pc) which accepts JDBC connection only. I am able to query via Oracle Sql Developer interface. I would like to create a web page that interacts with that database using php/apache. I have checked online and found PHP-JDBC bridge.

But it seems out of date and I am unable to use it. May someone advise on how to do this?

"PHP-JDBC BRIDGE"
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/JCotton1123/php-jdbc-bridge&ved=2ahUKEwitmtLNpu_dAhVIPo8KHZ3kAywQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw2c9unk2-bNWtwU6wA4_p65

Comment: The Oracle wire protocol is the same whether you use a JDBC driver, a PHP driver, the Oracle Native client, or another driver. So, you seem to be starting from the wrong assumption that you can use JDBC connections only (unless you have a nasty DBA that explicitly filters on a client driver attribute). If you want to use Oracle from PHP, use a more suitable solution (eg an Oracle driver for PHP, see https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/php.html) than trying to create a Frankenstein involving Java and PHP, or alternatively: write your service in Java, not in PHP.

Comment: @mark rotteveel thank you so much! I am now able to connect to the db via OCI8.